# ¿como ejecutar una función al hacer cambio de radio button?

Tags: jquery

Tengo la siguiente tabla dinamicamente con sus radio button.

```
    var donaciones = $('.donaciones');
       $.each(donativos, function(index,value){
         $('<tr>')
          .append($('<td/>').addClass('nuevo-td descripcion').text(value.Descripcion))
.append('<div class="tipo" style="display:none">' + value.Tipo + '</div>')
                                .append('<div class="codigoinventario" style="display:none">' + value.Codigo_Inventario + '</div>')
                                .append('<div class="cantidad" style="display:none">' + value.Cantidad + '</div>')
                                .append('<div class="tipo_costo" style="display:none">' + value.TipoCosto + '</div>')
                                .append('<div class="precio_socio" style="display:none">' + value.PrecioSocio + '</div>')
                                .append('<div class="volumen_negocio" style="display:none">' + value.VolumenNegocio + '</div>')
                                .append($('<td/>').addClass('label-cell nuevo-td classCantidad')
                                    .append($('<label/>').addClass('label-radio item-content')
                                                .append('<input type="radio" name="donacion" class="donacion" attr-num-doc="' + value.Codigo_Inventario + '" value="' + value.Codigo_Inventario + '"/>')
                                                .append($('<span/>').addClass('item-media').append('<i class="icon icon-form-radio"></i>'))))
                                .appendTo(donaciones);
                        });
```

al seleccionar un radio button ejecuto esta funcion:

```
$('.donaciones').on('change', '.donacion', function(e){
        let registro_donacion = $(this).closest('tr');
        let descripcion       = registro_donacion.find('.descripcion').text();
        let tipo              = registro_donacion.find('.tipo').text();
        let codigo_inventario = registro_donacion.find('.codigoinventario').text();
        let cantidad          = registro_donacion.find('.cantidad').text();
        let tipo_costo        = registro_donacion.find('.tipo_costo').text();
        let precio_socio      = registro_donacion.find('.precio_socio').text();
        let volumen_negocio   = registro_donacion.find('.volumen_negocio').text();


        console.log(descripcion);
        console.log(tipo);
        console.log(codigo_inventario);
        console.log(cantidad);
        console.log(tipo_costo);
        console.log(precio_socio);
        console.log(volumen_negocio);

        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            //agregarDonacion(idPedido, tipo, codigo_inventario, cantidad, tipo_costo, precio_socio, volumen_negocio);
        }
        else{
            console.log("Desmarcado");
        }
    });
```

Visualmente la tabla es de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema que tengo por ejemplo al seleccionar el radio button de "5.00" ejecuto la funcion `agregarDonacion` que se encuentra cuando selecciono radio button, pero cuando quiero hacer el cambio al radio button de "10.00" debo antes ejecutar une funcino `eliminarDonacion` para eliminar los valores del registro "5.00" que habia seleccionado anteriormente.

muchas gracias.

Comment: No queda claro cual es tu problema..

Comment: De que si inicialmente seleccione 5.00 eso  lo debo guardar, y luego al hacer el cambio a 10.00 debe eliminarme el valor 5.00 y agregar el nuevo valor 10.00

Comment: Radio button list

Comment: JG_GJ, no está claro. parece que necesitas implementar otra funcion para eliminar la opcion anterior. Aunque no entiendo que permitas cambiar de opcion e inmediatamente estés mandando la donacion. seria mejor dejar al usuario seleccionar la que sea y luego mandarla cuando esté seguro que es esa la que quiere mandar.